# How to convert date column from Object format to date format with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a column with values like `2023-06-13T15:11:24.020000+00:00`. I checked the format of this column after importing as a Pandas DF (imported from csv) and I see it is in `object` format. How can I convert the column to the date format and remove timestamp and have values like `2023-06-13` or any other date format?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.normalize()`